# Как программно составить список обслуживаемых хостов в NodeJS (нативно)?

Tags: node.js, localhost, virtual-hosts

Как я узнал из [англоязычного Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70358184/4818123), валидация HTTP-заголовка HOST с помощью регулярных выражений, учитывающая все возможные сценарии, может привести к довольно сложному регулярному выражению. Однако достаточно проверить, входит ли значение полученного HTTP-заголовка HOST в список поддерживаемых (тем более, что валидация с помощью регулярного выражения всё равно не избавляет от необходимости этой проверки). Чтобы реализовать эти проверки, необходимо знать всё возможные варианты валидного заголовка HOST для своего случая.

### "Поддерживаемые хосты следует прописывать вручную"

Мне это говорили неоднократно, да я в полной мере этого и не отвергаю. Всё равно нужно прописать в явном виде основной хост, например **example.com**. А теперь представим, что у этого **example.com** - десятой-другой поддоменов, причём у каждого есть ещё одни поддомен под локаль. Плюс к этому, в режиме локальной разработки нужно, чтобы сервер не отвергал запросы , идущие на `localhost`. Наконец, есть какие-то редкие частные случаи типа `example.com.`, которые по-хорошему тоже надо учитывать.

И что? Мне предлагается всё это прописать вручную?

```
[
  "example.com",
  "XXX.X.X.X", // IP-адрес сервера с "example.com"
  "example.com:8080", 
  "XXX.X.X.X:8080",
  // + всё то же самое для localhost в режиме локальной разработки
  // + какие-то редкие частные случаи

  /* --- поддомены локали для "example.com" --- */
  "ru.example.com",
  "ru.XXX.X.X.X",
  "ru.example.com:8080", 
  "ru.XXX.X.X.X:8080",
  // + всё то же самое для localhost в режиме локальной разработки

  "en.example.com",
  "en.XXX.X.X.X",
  "en.example.com:8080", 
  "en.XXX.X.X.X:8080",
  // + всё то же самое для localhost в режиме локальной разработки

  // и так для всех поддерживаемых языков ...

  /* --- поддомен "cats" --- */ 
  "cats.example.com",
  "cats.XXX.X.X.X",
  "cats.example.com:8080", 
  "cats.XXX.X.X.X:8080",
  // + всё то же самое для localhost в режиме локальной разработки

  /* --- поддомены локали для "cats.example.com" --- */
  "ru.cats.example.com",
  "ru.cats.XXX.X.X.X",
  "ru.cats.example.com:8080", 
  "ru.cats.XXX.X.X.X:8080",
  // + всё то же самое для localhost в режиме локальной разработки

  // и так для всех поддерживаемых языков ...

  // и так для всех поддоменов
]
```

Очень надеюсь, что нет (по крайней мере, для третьего десятилетия 21 века).
Полагаю, что более рациональный подход состоит в том, чтобы прописать только какие-то исходные данные (это будут основной хост, например `example.com`, поддерживаемые поддомены, например `cats`, `dogs` и т. д. + поддерживаемые локали), а всё возможные варианты - вычислить программно. И тогда уже при каждом запросе будем проверять HTTP-заголовок HOST на совпадение с одним из допустимых вариантов.

Изложу всё, что сам узнал по данной тематике.

### Режим локальной разработки

В режиме локальной разработке обычно используется `localhost`. Вроде как, им не обязательно должен быть IP-адрес `127.0.0.1`, но при каких условиях `localhost` будет ссылаться на другие IP-адреса - мне неизвестно. Да и вообще, попытки узнать, как резолвить `localhost` в IP-адрес, [пока не увенчались успехом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1365115/193415). Была подсказка, что можно с помощью нативных утилит определить соответствие localhost и IP-адреса.

Таким образом, при обслуживании IP-адреса `127.0.0.1` и порта 80 (по умолчанию для HTTP), валидными будут следующие заголовки HOST:

- `127.0.0.1`
- `localhost`
- `127.0.0.1:80`
- `localhost:80`

При этом, перед сравнением присланного заголовка с одним из валидным из списка удобно будет:

1. Добавить порт по умолчанию, если таковой не указан.
2. Убрать нули в начале номера порта, если таковые имеются (например: 0080 -> 80).

В итоге, список обслуживаемых хостов сокращается до:

- `127.0.0.1:80`
- `localhost:80`

Для HTTPS, соответственно, порт по умолчанию будет `443`.
Если же порт будет не умолчанию - то после двоеточия будет номер этого порта.

Если я правильно понял, что до меня хотели донести в одном из комментариев, то в режиме локальной разработки проверку заголовка HOST можно вообще опустить. Не уверен в этом по двум причинам:

1. Нужно отладить механизм валидации заголовка HOST до деплоя
2. Помимо безопасности, анализ заголовка HOST нужен в приложениях, обслуживающих несколько поддоменов.

### Режим продакшена

Полагаю, с режиме продакшена `localhost`-а не будет, а вместо `127.0.0.1` будет тот IP-адрес, который выдал провайдер VPS.

- Если на этот IP-адрес зарегистрировано доменное имя, то в список нужно будет добавить валидный вариант с этим доменным именем (например, `example.com:80`).
- С портами всё остаётся так же.

### Поддержка поддоменов

Думаю, список поддерживаемых поддоменов должен быть конечным. Если часть поддомена является параметризованной (например локаль, как `ru` в `ru.stackoverflow.com`), то все возможные значения должны быть заранее известны (прописаны в настройках). Тогда, для `example.com` с двумя поддоменами и IP-адрсом `000.0.0.0` получаем такой список:

- 000.0.0.0:80
- example.com:80
- ru.000.0.0.0:80
- en.000.0.0.0:80
- ru.example.com:80
- en.example.com:80

### Напоследок

Прошу Вас не рекомендовать никаких готовых решений типа express-плагинов, так как в данном вопросе речь идёт о именно о самостоятельной реализации механизма валидации HTTP-заголовка HOST.

Comment: Обычно список обслуживаемых хостов не составляют программно, а прописывают вручную в каком-нибудь файле конфигурации. Обслуживать на продакшене localhost, IP-адреса и тысячи привязанных к этому IP-адресу непонятно каких доменов и поддоменов как минимум неразумно, как максимум опасно

Comment: А ещё вы забыли о существовании доменов с точкой на конце `example.com.:80` — впрочем, об этом и так забывают почти все :)

Comment: 1. Какую задачу решаете? Делаете свой веб-сервер? Посмотрите сорцы веб-серверов Nginx/Apache/...  2. `но при каких условиях localhost будет ссылаться на другие IP-адреса - мне неизвестно`  - выполните `cat /etc/hosts`, там прописано соответствие localhost <=> 127.0.0.1. Теперь поменяйте IP адрес в этом файле на 127.0.0.2, например, и пропингуйте `ping localhost` - увидите уже этот новый IP. Также посмотрите что такое [loopback](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-loopback-address)

Comment: @TotalPusher 1. Создание бэкенд фреймворка со учётом всех базовых требований по безопасности. 2. Спасибо! Посмотрю.

Comment: > Создание бэкенд фреймворка со учётом всех базовых требований по безопасности - я тут недавно, под давлением log4j - паники, познакомился стакой штукой, как Amazon WAF. Я не предлагаю им воспользоваться, но его "интерфейс" и задачи, котрые он решает, выглядяд очень разумно. Можно глянуть на описание здесь: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/waf/getting-started/ А еще: из практики, обычно на входе ставят nginx с набором правил фильтрации...

Comment: Не знаю ваших замутов с доменами, но в качестве морды в интернет почти для всего я использую сокеты systemd. Во первых если поднимать сервер в качестве сервиса systemd, мы получаем возможность управлять сервером через команды, такие как `systemctl`, `journalctl` и проч., отпадает надобность использовать логгеры, логротаторы, тупо весь лог льём используя `console.log()`, systemd лучше других знает состояние всего класстера и в случае неполадки, он всегда может перезагрузить и сервер и хоть всю машину и всегда просигнализирует об этом в центр принятия решений, туда же автоматом выгрузит логи.

Comment: Но самое главное - systemd может выключать неиспользуемый сервер, ждать соединения и при запросе автоматом самостоятельно включить сервер, при этом ответить браузеру и держать сокет до полной загрузке сервера, потом выдав страничку - без всяких там ошибок 503....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживаемые хосты действительно следует прописывать вручную, однако это не подразумевает составления списка с перебором всех возможных вариантов. К этой задаче следует подходить с другой стороны - с разбора хоста. Хост предствляет собой запись вида

```
<ipv4|ipv6|domain>:<opt_port>
```

При этом доменное имя не может пересекаться с адресом ipv6, так как в нем не разрешается `:`, и не может пересекаться с адресом ipv4, так как домен верхнего уровня не может состоять только из чисел. т.е. вариантов вида `ru.000.0.0.0:80` быть не может. А если используется адрес ipv6 и указывается порт, то адрес должен быть в квадратных скобках. Эти ограничения позволяют однозначно разобрать хост на компоненты за один проход не прибегая ни к каким регулярным выражениям. Причем разбор имеет смысл производить с конца, сразу определив опциональный порт, а затем перейдя к разбору адреса или домена. Получая адрес проверить его валидность тривиально по плоскому перечню разрешенных адресов. Доменное имя как раз тоже важно разбирать с конца, так как там находятся домены более высокого уровня, и получая домен
его валидность тоже несложно проверить по иерархическому перечню разрешенных доменов, начиная навигацию с домена верхнего уровня, например подобного:

```
{
   "com":
   {
       "option1":...
   ,   "subdomains":
       {
           "example":
           {
               "option1":...
           ,   "subdomain":
               {
                   "ru":
                   {
                       "option1":...
                   }
               ,   "en":
                   {
                       "option1":...
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

По сути это карта сайта по иерархии доменов. И в ней же можно сразу прописывать обработчики и какие-то нужные настройки для поддерживаемых доменов.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Приступил к написанию кода согласно этой теории. Прошу прощения, к сожалению не понял, почему не может быть "ru.000.0.0.0:80". Если мы локально ведём разработку с хоста "000.0.0.0:80" и хотим протестировать поддомен "ru", то какой же у нас тогда будет заголовок HOST кроме как "ru.000.0.0.0:80"?

Comment: @БоковГлеб В ответе же написано почему - `домен верхнего уровня не может состоять только из чисел`, так что `ru.000.0.0.0` - невалидное доменное имя. Чтобы протестировать поддомен локально, необходимо будет настроить DNS чтобы например доменное имя `ru.localhost` перенаправлялось на 127.0.0.1.