# Как в node.js нативно преобразовать localhost в IP-адрес?

Tags: node.js

Нативные модули `http` и `https` не требуют указания хоста для запуска простого сервера. Полагаю, что в целях безопасности необходимо решить, какой именно хост будет обслуживаться, а затем уже отклонять запросы с заголовками HOST, не удовлетворяющему настройкам.

Допустим, мы обслуживаем `127.0.0.1:1337`. Однако запросы с заголовками `localhost:1337` будут невалидными, если мы будем проверять заголовок на соответствие подстроке `127.0.0.1`. Да, мы-то знаем, что в данном случае `localhost` - это местоимение для `127.0.0.1`, но ведь так бывает не всегда. Поэтому чтобы пометить `localhost` как валидный, нужно на программном уровне преобразовать `localhost` в `127.0.0.1:1337`. Но как это сделать нативно?

Прошу в данном вопросе не рекомендовать никаких библиотек и фреймворков, так здесь речь идёт именно о самостоятельной реализации этого функционала нативными средствами.

Comment: Конкретно для 127.0.0.1 вообще-то нет никакого смысла проверять хост. И если уж делать фильтрацию, то логично наоборт запрещать ip.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, так если запрос дошёл до сервера, значит домен ресолвится в то, что надо.

Comment: `curl http://localhost/ -H 'Host: google.com'` Домен подделывается на раз

Comment: @AlexeyTen, чтобы этого избежать, нужно проверять соответствие заголовка с URL запроса?

Comment: Что бы этого избежать надо сначала решить какие имена хостов разрешены. А все остальные запретить.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Да я собственно, с этого-то и начинал и даже задавал [вопрос по этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1364050/193415). Хост `127.0.0.1:80` я разрешил - это нетрудно, но `localhost`-то не теперь валиден! Вот и встал вопрос, что делать, когда придёт `localhost:80` вместо `127.0.0.1:80`...

Comment: начать нужно с того, что бы понять какой смысл приложению которое слушает только 127.0.0.1 вообще что-то запрещать

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ну вообще я имел в виду при отправке из браузера. Отправку запроса curl'ом как-то сомнительно использовать против пользователя сайта. Можно ещё в системе прокси поставить, но это опять же действия за пределами песочницы.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Я правильно Вас понял, что если приложение случает хост в диапазоне `127.0.0.1 — 127.255.255.254`, то вводить ограничения по хостам бессмысленно?

Comment: Если оно вообще не торчит наружу, то непонятно от кого защита. А если торчит, то перед ним есть какой-то reverse proxy (nginx, haproxy и т. п.) и хост логичнее проверять там, и не трогать лишний раз приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял вопроса, но очень подозреваю, что ты хочешь сделать это:

```
const http = require("http")

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.end("hi")
}).listen(1337, "0.0.0.0")
```

> Или может быть, раз запрос дошёл до сервера, то его можно не валидировать? Безопасно ли это?

Любой сайт может в dns прописать ссылку на любой ip и это будет валидно. Т. е. любая третья сторона может сделать так, что домен, которым она владеет, будет совершенно законно мапиться на твой ip-адрес.

Я совершенно не вижу смысла пытаться выяснить, ресолвится ли присланный хост в твой ip или нет. В случае браузера подмена хоста из песочницы страницы невозможна. В случае вмешательства через расширения (установка прокси) или в систему (файл hosts) или самостоятельной отправки запроса через wget, curl или другие утилиты можно послать что угодно, но я не вижу повода для проверки таких штук в автоматическом режиме.

Что касается безопасности, dns remapping может являться уязвимостью. Посторонний сайт может указать твой ip в качестве своего и быстро меняя ip между своим сайтом и твоим сможет обходить кроссдоменность при отправке запрсов.

Но возвращаясь к твоему вопросу, в этом варианте их домен совершенно законно мапится на твой ip, и если ты попытаешься проверить, соответствует ли домен ip-адресу, то со значительной вероятностью результат проверки будет положительным.

Чтобы избежать dns remapping'а, надо чтобы сайт знал свой хост (или список допустимых хостов) и работал только с ними. Автоматическое определение тут не поможет.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ и прошу прощения за непонятный вопрос. Тогда задам его так: если придёт заголовок HOST со значением `localhost:1337` вместо `0.0.0.0:1331`, то что делать - отвечать `hi` как у Вас в примере или отправить Bad Request с сообщением типа "такой хост не обслуживается"? Полагаю, в данном случае будет "отвечать `hi`", но откуда мы на программном уровне знаем, что `localhost` - это тоже самое, что `0.0.0.0`? А если у нас режим продакшена, а не локальной разработки? Или может быть, раз запрос дошёл до сервера, то его можно не валидировать? Безопасно ли это?

Comment: @БоковГлеб, ответил.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробное объяснение. Я правильно понял, что под "знал свой хост" Вы имеет ввиду  `.listen(1337, "0.0.0.0")`? Если да, то на этом данный вопрос исчерпан.